# how to make this nginx location redirect not case sensitive

Tags: redirect, nginx, location

**my situation:**

domain.com is a WordPress site (and WP works fine). its installed at the root.
I also created/add a sub folder:  domain.com/subfolder

that has an index.php page in it, like so:
domain.com/subfolder/index.php

I need any URL entered into browser to redirect to subfolder index.php page.

I have this nginx location, but it ONLY works if you type in case sensitive subfolder or subfolder/, I need non-sensitive:

```
location /subfolder {
return 301 http://domain.com/subfolder/index.php;
}


location /subfolder/ {
return 301 http://domain.com/subfolder/index.php;
}
```

SO basically, if user types anything except subfolder or subfolder/, let WP take care of the url. otherwise, redirect it.

I've tried ~ ^ *, but can't get it to work right.
what am i doing wrong? :)

thanks!

PS. if you see something else that I should be doing, please let me know -- i'm new to nginx

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
location ~* /subfolder/ {
return 301 http://domain.com/subfolder/index.php;
}
```

The `tilde` and `asterisks` ensure that this location will be matched case insensitive.

Comment: thanks, but i tried that, but it does not work when you add a capital letter, like this: /Subfolder

the URL will be transfer/processed by WP

note: i've read that "should" work... what could be reason on why that doesn't work?